# How to find out number of webservices call in installed android apps?

Tags: android

I want to find out if an Android application makes calls to remote web services.

Comment: webservices? maybe you mean android services?

Comment: no..the number of server call means webservices

Answer (score 0):

You can try to decompile apks and then analize the source code. I would suggest this book [http://www.amazon.com/Decompiling-Android-Godfrey-Nolan/dp/1430242485](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430242485)

Comment: i dont want to decomplie source code..i want to track the annother apps server call